# Obtener la suma del valor de un objeto

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo un objeto al que le hago un Object.keys y a eso un map y accedo a cada valor para mandarlos a una tabla. El problema es que no se como obtener la suma total de Quantity de los que tengan. Solo obtengo la suma total de Descripcion. Mi objeto es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para obtener la Quantity total de las Marca que tengan el mismo nombre? Lo que actualmente hago es lo siguiente:

```
((Object.keys(groupByClientFinancing).map(name => {
        return groupByClientFinancing[`${name}`].map(data => {
            return {
                MARCA: data.Marca,
                MODELO: data.Descripcion,
                 Monto:  groupByClientFinancing[`${name}`].filter(seller=> data.Descripcion === seller.Descripcion && true).reduce((a,b) => a + b.Quantity, 0),
            }
        })
```

Pero así solo obtengo la suma de todos los Descripcion que coincidan. Intenté cambiando seller.Descripcion por seller.Marca pero obtengo lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo actual no puedo realmente saber si tienes todas las marcas en un solo array o en distintos arrays o en un array multi dimensional.

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente aplane los arrays

```
let mergedArrays = [].concat.apply([], arrayMultiDimensional);
```

Tambien cree un set de descripciones, en javascript un set es un array con valores unicos.

```
let uniqueDescs = [...new Set(mergedArrays.map(x => x.Descripcion))]
```

Y cree una variable que almacenara todos los valores de las cantidades totales

```
let totalQuantities = [];
```

Luego lo que hice fue iterar en un loop sobre las descripciones y en cada iteracion creaba un objeto con cada descripcion de mi set, y para obtener las cantidades totales usaba el array donde aplane los demas arrays y con el metodo `filter()` buscaba los objetos cuyas descripciones fueran igual a item y  con el metodo `reduce()` sacaba el total de los objetos encontrados.

```
for(let item of uniqueDescs) {
  totalQuantities
    .push({
      Descripcion: item, 
      Total: mergedArrays.filter(x => x.Descripcion === item).reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur.Quantity, 0)
      })
}
```

Te dejo un link con un demo funcional y espero te haya servido mi ayuda.
https://playcode.io/855996/

Comment: Gracias! Pero lo que tengo si es un array multi dimensional en el que tengo todo. Adjunto una imagen para que puedas ver. En este caso se puede aplicar la misma lógica como lo hiciste?

Comment: Agregué una imagen al post de cómo es mi array

Comment: Si es lo mismo var arrayAplanado= [].concat.apply([], arrayMultiDimensional); ya modifique la respuesta dame aceptame la respuesta :v

Comment: Jaja muchas gracias! Me funciona pero fuera del Object.Keys y necesito mandarlo dentro para poder mandar esos datos a la tabla. Como puedo hacer eso dentro del Object.keys? Por ej en la parte de:  return {
                MARCA: data.Marca,
                MODELO: data.Descripcion,
                 Monto:  groupByClientFinancing[`${name}`].filter(seller=> data.Descripcion === seller.Descripcion && true).reduce((a,b) => a + b.Quantity, 0),
            }

Como puedo mandar todo en otro valor abajo de Monto: ?